# Indent for second line of chapter/section title

Tags: sectioning

I have got a simple problem concerning multi-line chapter/section titles, that I could not fix.

This is how it is:

[image]

and this is how I want it to be:

[image]

(I want the second line of the title to line up with the first one)

I have read somehow relevant answers who use the `titlesec` package. As far as possible I want to avoid that. I read a few pages in the KOMA guide but without a solution.
Please tell me, if you know some KOMA-options or KOMA-commands to fix this.

Thank you in advance.

**edit:**
I am sorry, but I forgott the probably most important thing: used `\newline` or `\\` because the hypertension was ugly.

MWE:
I noticed, that I made a mistake in the description of my problem. I used `\\` or `\newline` to break the line. Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper, 
11pt
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \section{Title long enough to flow in the second line\\ and indent matching the previous line}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide minimal working example which show your problem.

Comment: If you compile `\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}
  \section {Title long enough to flow in the second line and indent matching the previous line}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{document}` you get what you desired. So, we need a MWE.

Comment: I noticed, that I made a mistake in the description of my problem. I used \\ or \newline to break the line. Here the MWE: \documentclass[%
a4paper, 
11pt
]{scrreprt}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
 \section{Title long enough to flow in the second line\\ and indent matching the previous line}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491339/indent-wrapped-chapter-title | https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522359/indent-for-second-line-in-long-chapter-title | Reverse question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628624/justify-section-number-and-multi-line-section-title

Answer (score 3):

Using `\newline` instead `\\` works for me:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Title long enough to flow in the second line\newline and indent matching the previous line}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But note that the same line break will be in the table of Contents. To avoid this use the optional argument of `\section`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section
  [Title long enough to flow in the second line and indent matching the previous line]
  {Title long enough to flow in the second line\newline and indent matching the previous line}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok. It works in my or your MWE, but not in my "real" document. How could I have changed that (not on purpose). Do you know some packages, that change this behaviour. (I did **not** use `titlesec` for now)

Comment: You have to expand your MWE a little bit so that it shows this problem with `\newline` too. If you are German then you can read the instructions in http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/569/was-ist-ein-vollstandiges-minimalbeispiel-oder-kurz-vm-und-wie-erstelle-ich-dieses/570

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\hspace{0em}}{}
  \begin{document}
  \section {Title long enough to flow in the second line and indent matching the previous line}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed, that I made a mistake in the description of my problem. I used \\ or \newline to break the line. Here the MWE: \documentclass[%
a4paper, 
11pt
]{scrreprt}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
 \section{Title long enough to flow in the second line\\ and indent matching the previous line}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document} I don't want to use the titlesec package if it is not necessary...