# Indent for second line in long chapter title

Tags: chapters, titlesec, alignment

I am using the book class to write a document. I have a long chapter title that only fits in two lines. I'm using a custom chapter heading font and the justification of the chapter title in the second line is hidden by the black box.

[image: what I have]
[image: what I want]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec,calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{18}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{
    \raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%<<
        \begin{minipage}{20mm}
            \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\normalsize\textsc{Chapter}}\\[5pt]%
            \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
            \raisebox{23mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\LARGE\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}}%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \rule{\textwidth-20mm}{.4pt}\\%
    \hspace*{20mm}  
}[\vspace*{10mm}]


\begin{document}

\chapter{This is an example of a very long title that only fits in two lines}

    \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

How do I do this please ?

Comment: The baseline distance of your "want to have" example is greater than that of the original, non-indented, example.  If that is significant, please make that clear.

Comment: Because the **want to have** version was edited manually as an image. Otherwise it's not significant, I keep the default baseline distance.

Comment: See also [sectioning - Indent for second line of chapter/section title - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271194/indent-for-second-line-of-chapter-section-title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the chapter title in a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec,calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{18}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{
    \raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%<<
        \begin{minipage}{20mm}
            \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\normalsize\textsc{Chapter}}\\[5pt]%
            \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
            \raisebox{23mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\LARGE\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}}%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \rule{\textwidth-22mm}{.4pt}\\%
    \hspace*{22mm}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-22mm}
}[\end{minipage}\vspace*{10mm}]

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is an example of a very long title that only fits in two lines}
    \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant: I changed the chapterstyle to `block`, put the chapter title in a `\parbox` of width `\linegoal`, which measures the length from the current point to the right margin and used `\titlerule`, which simply fills  the line from the current point to the right margin.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\fontsize{18}{16}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\bfseries}{}{0pt}{
    \raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%<<
        \begin{minipage}{20mm}
            \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\normalsize\textsc{Chapter}}\\[5pt]%
            \medskip\rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
            \raisebox{23mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\LARGE\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}}%
        \end{minipage}
}%
 \titlerule\\%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr20mm +0.5em}
\parbox{\linegoal} }[\vspace*{10mm}]

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is an example of a very long title that only fits in two lines}

    \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]