# Justify section number and multi-line section title

Tags: section-titles

I have long sections' titles and latex renders them like this

```
21. Very very very very very very
    very very very very very very
    very very very very very very
    Long section title example

This is the text below title.
```

but I want to render them without offset for number on the left like this:

```
21. Very very very very very very
very very very very very very
very very very very very very
Long section title example

This is the text below title.
```

How can I do it? Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\section{Very very very very very very
 very very very very very
 very very very very very
 section title example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may try the `runin` or `block` shape of the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve your typesetting objective with the help of the `sectsty` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\parindent0pt\nohang\raggedright}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example

\section{An example of a very very very very very very
    very very very very very very
    very very very very very very
    long section title}

This is some text below the section header.

This is some more text below the section header.
\end{document}
```